# Intuition for perceptron weight update rule

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, perceptron

I am having trouble understanding the weight update rule for [perceptrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Steps):

*w(t + 1) = w(t) + y(t)x(t)*.

Assume we have a linearly separable data set.

- *w* is a set of weights [w0, w1, w2, ...] where w0 is a bias.
- *x* is a set of input parameters [x0, x1, x2, ...] where x0 is fixed at 1 to accommodate the bias.

At iteration *t*, where *t* = 0, 1, 2, ...,

- *w(t)* is the set of weights at iteration *t*.
- *x(t)* is a misclassified training example.
- *y(t)* is the target output of *x(t)* (either -1 or 1).

---

Why does this update rule move the boundary in the right direction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The perceptron's output is the hard limit of the dot product between the instance and the weight. Let's see how this changes after the update. Since

*w(t + 1) = w(t) + y(t)x(t)*,

then

*x(t) ⋅ w(t + 1) = x(t) ⋅ w(t) + x(t) ⋅ (y(t) x(t)) = x(t) ⋅ w(t) + y(t) [x(t) ⋅ x(t))]*.

---

Note that:

- By the algorithm's specification, the update is only applied if *x(t)* was misclassified.
- By the definition of the dot product, *x(t) ⋅ x(t) ≥ 0*.

---

How does this move the boundary relative to *x(t)*?

- If *x(t)* was correctly classified, then the algorithm does not apply the update rule, so nothing changes.
- If *x(t)* was incorrectly classified as negative, then *y(t) = 1*. It follows that the new dot product increased by *x(t) ⋅ x(t)* (which is positive). The boundary moved in the right direction as far as *x(t)* is concerned, therefore.
- Conversely, if *x(t)* was incorrectly classified as positive, then *y(t) = -1*. It follows that the new dot product decreased by *x(t) ⋅ x(t)* (which is positive). The boundary moved in the right direction as far as *x(t)* is concerned, therefore.

Comment: Can you expand a little on the last sentence? What happens when *x(t)* is classified and  when *x(t)* is misclassified?

Comment: well that happens when its updated as y(t)/x(t) as well, keeping w(t+1) unitless, I don't understand why weight is updated proportional to the y(t).x(t).

Answer (score 3):

A better derivation of the perceptron update rule is documented [here](https://lucidar.me/en/neural-networks/simplest-perceptron-update-rules-demonstration/) and [here](https://lucidar.me/en/neural-networks/learning-rule-demonstration/). The derivation is using gradient descent.

- Basic premise of gradient descent algorithm is find the error of classification and make your parameters so that error is minimized.

PS:
I was trying very hard to get the intuition on why would someone multiply x and y to derive the update for w. Because w is the slope for a single dimension (y = wx+c) and slope w = (y/x) and not y * x.

Comment: What did you come up to your PS? That's exact confusion I have.